# Constructing a matrix from eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products, positive-definite

At minute 9.10 of this lecture https://library.cirm-math.fr/Record.htm?idlist=1&record=19285368124910035409 the slide claims that a particular matrix solves a Lemma, I cant see why.

---

Here I will simplify the setting and state my question. Consider a matrix $C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which is positive semi-definite ( hence symmetric ) and hence has all real eigenvalues with the minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_C^{\text{min}}\geq 0$. Assume that $C$ is non-defective (its geometric multiplicity is equal to its algebraic multiplicity). Then define $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as

$$ P:= \sum_{k=1}^n z_k \otimes z_k^T,$$
where $z_k$ are the eigenvectors of $C$. $\textbf{Question :}$ why is it that $P$ is such that

$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ PC^T + CP \geq 2\lambda_C^{\text{min}} P ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~? $$

I haven't done linear algebra like this for a while.

---

Notation :

- $^T$ is the transpose,
- $\otimes$ is the tensor product, i.e $ ( a \otimes b )_{i,j}= a_ib_j$

Comment: "Assume that $C$ is non-defective" I think this follows automatically from being symmetric.

Comment: I thought it might - thanks !

Comment: Side remark: it's ‘positive semi-definite’, not ‘positive-semi definite’.

Comment: @user1551 oops my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the $z_k$s together to form a square matrix $Z$. Since they are eigenvectors of $C$, we have $CZ=Z\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix whose $k$-th diagonal entry is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $z_k$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
PC^T+CP-2\lambda_\min(C)P
&=ZZ^TC^T+CZZ^T-2\lambda_\min(C)ZZ^T\\
&=2Z\Lambda Z^T-2\lambda_\min(C)ZZ^T\\
&=2Z(\Lambda-\lambda_\min(C)I)Z^T,
\end{aligned}
which is $\ge0$ because $\Lambda-\lambda_\min(C)I$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix.

*Remark.* Note that we do not need the $z_k$s to form an eigenbasis of $C$. One can pick a linearly dependent set of eigenvectors. In this case $Z$ is singular, but $2Z(\Lambda-\lambda_\min(C)I)Z^T$ is still positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks I just read through it. I might buzz you if theres a detail I dont understand. But seems rather simple. It made it much easier writing $P = Z Z^T$ :)